# Drupal authcache - load dynamic content through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, caching

I'm using Drupal 6 with [authcache](http://drupal.org/project/authcache). I've read that you can load dynamic content by using ajax, even when the whole page is cached with authcache. In my template files, I've used this code to show Edit and Delete links:

`<?php if ($user->uid == $node->uid || in_array('moderator', array_values($user->roles))|| $user->uid == 1): ?>
<span class="edit"><?php print l('Edit', 'node/' . $nid . '/edit'); ?></span>
<span class="delete"><?php print l('Delete', 'node/' . $nid . '/delete'); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>`

This checks if the user is either: The owner of the content, a moderator, or the super administrator. How could I make that part load with ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you try [Authcache ajax docs](http://drupal.org/node/996460) or on the example.com/admin/build/modules enable the authcache example block module (it is axample on how to achieve this) and try to go through this module for an inspiration. I haven't tried to test it yet but I came over that during installation of the Authcache module.

If I were you I would try to assynchrounously load the content through ajax link to your links function.

Hope it helps.

Lukas